# Select all checkboxes / rows - React hooks app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm struggling with checking off all checkboxes at once within a table.
I can check of individual checkboxes, however I also want the option to check off
one "master checkbox", which checks all the other ones off.

I've created a simplyfied version of my React component:
https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-wildflower-fknn9

There are two things with this I'm struggling with.

1. If we remove the checked attribute on each of the two checkboxes, we can manually check each one and get it printed out to console. If we override the checked parameter by setting it to `checked={checkAll}` we can click the All checkbox, and both checkbox 1 and two gets checked off. However, it does not invoke the `onChange` attribute of the checkbox, which means I'm not able to record the checks.
2. If I put on the `checked={checkAll}` attribute, I'm basically overriding the checkbox, which means the checkbox icon itself won't change from checked to unchecked. The `onChange` attribute is however invoked, and I'm able to record the change to the console.

I would like to check both checkboxes individually, and also use the "master checkbox" to check off both checkboxes, and invoke their `onChange` at the same time.

How can I go about doing this?
Any suggestions would be super helpful

Comment: Here's how to do this: https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-jackson-h6c4p?file=/src/App.js The key is to not override anything but to simply change the state of all checkboxes when the *all* checkbox is changed.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for taking your time. I was able to take some of the principles in your example and make my app work as its supposed to. I used one state for handling the actual selected items. I also had a different state for the UI (click, select all, deselect and so forth.) Once I got both to work simultaneously in parallell, I solved my issue. Thanks. You may create some form of a general answer which I can accept.

Answer (score 7):

This is a way of handling it:

[CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-framework-8l2ez?file=/src/App.js)

This is the final behavior:

[image]

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [checkedAll, setCheckedAll] = useState(false);
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState({
    nr1: false,
    nr2: false
  });

  /* ################################################ */
  /* #### TOGGLES checK STATE BASED ON inputName #### */
  /* ################################################ */

  const toggleCheck = (inputName) => {
    setChecked((prevState) => {
      const newState = { ...prevState };
      newState[inputName] = !prevState[inputName];
      return newState;
    });
  };

  /* ###################################################### */
  /* #### CHECKS OR UNCHECKS ALL FROM SELECT ALL CLICK #### */
  /* ###################################################### */

  const selectAll = (value) => {
    setCheckedAll(value);
    setChecked((prevState) => {
      const newState = { ...prevState };
      for (const inputName in newState) {
        newState[inputName] = value;
      }
      return newState;
    });
  };

  /* ############################################# */
  /* #### EFFECT TO CONTROL CHECKED_ALL STATE #### */
  /* ############################################# */

  // IF YOU CHECK BOTH INDIVIDUALLY. IT WILL ACTIVATE THE checkedAll STATE
  // IF YOU UNCHECK ANY INDIVIDUALLY. IT WILL DE-ACTIVATE THE checkAll STATE

  useEffect(() => {
    let allChecked = true;
    for (const inputName in checked) {
      if (checked[inputName] === false) {
        allChecked = false;
      }
    }
    if (allChecked) {
      setCheckedAll(true);
    } else {
      setCheckedAll(false);
    }
  }, [checked]);

  /* ########################## */
  /* #### RETURN STATEMENT #### */
  /* ########################## */

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <label>All</label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          onChange={(event) => selectAll(event.target.checked)}
          checked={checkedAll}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>1</label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="nr1"
          onChange={() => toggleCheck("nr1")}
          checked={checked["nr1"]}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>2</label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="nr2"
          onChange={() => toggleCheck("nr2")}
          checked={checked["nr2"]}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is a good one, and easy but when you use array of checkbox with "map", how can you set one check for all ?