# How to change the checkbox selection and get the updated id's of checkbox items in form submit in React Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need help in my react code. I am displaying the list of checkbox items using api. My JSON file contains the data which is having `IsAssigned True/False`. If `isAssigned` is `true` for that item, item checkbox will be pre-checked on page load.

Now, I want to change the selection of Checkboxlist items. How can I get the id's of selected Checkboxes and call post/put api calls to make changes in the database.

There are checkboxes that are pre-selected `isAssigned=true`, unselect the pre-selected checkboxes `isAssigned= false`, select the checkboxes that are not pre-selected earlier.

Please find my react code and json data below. Also, help me out on achieving the above,

```js
import React from "react";

export class SetDescItems extends React.Component {

       static displayName = Assign_TemplateDescriptions.name;

 

       constructor(props) {

             super(props);

             this.state = {

                    ProdDescrlist: [],

                    checkedItems: new Map(),

             }

 

                    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

                    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

       }

 

       handleChange(event) {

             var isChecked = event.target.checked;

             var item = event.target.value;

             var id = event.target.id;

             this.setState(prevState => ({ checkedItems: prevState.checkedItems.set(id, item, isChecked) }));

       }

 

      handleSubmit(event) {
             event.preventDefault();
             //Create an Array.
             var checkedItems = new Array();

         //Reference all the CheckBoxes

             var chks = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
          // Loop and push the checked CheckBox id's in Array.

             for (var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++) {

                    if (chks[i].checked) {
                           checkedItems.push(chks[i].id);
               }
            }

      //Display the selected CheckBox id's.

             if (checkedItems.length > 0) {

                    checkedItems = checkedItems.join(",");

                    console.log("Selected ids: " + checkedItems);

             }

             const data = checkedItems;
             //write post api here
             

       }

 

       componentDidMount() {

                    this.getProdDescriptions();

       }

 

       async getProdDescriptions () {

             const url = “/api/getDescriptions”;

             await fetch(url)

                    .then(response => response.json())

                    .then((data) => {

                           this.setState({

                                 ProdDescrlist: data,

                                 loading: false

                           })

                           console.log(this.state.ProdDescrlist)

                    })

       }

       render() {

             return (

                    <div>

                           <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >

                                

                                                      <ul style={{ listStyle: 'none' }}>

                                                            {

                                                                   (this.state.ProdDescrlist.map((item, index) => {

                                                                          return (

 

                                                                                <li key={index}>

                                                                                      <input type="checkbox"

                                                                                             id={item.ProdDescription_ID}

                                                                                             defaultChecked={item.isAssigned == "TRUE"?true:false}

                                                                                             value={item.DescriptionTextPlain}

                                                                                             onChange={this.handleChange} />

                                                                                     

                                                                                             &nbsp;{item.DescriptionTextPlain}

                                                                                     

                                                                                </li>

                                                                         )

                                                                   }

                                                                   ))

                                                            }

                                                            </ul>

                                                      <button type="submit">Submit</button>

                                                                                            

                           </form>

                    </div>

 

             );

       }

}

 

export default SetDescItems;
```

[{"ProdDescription_ID":2863,"isAssigned":"TRUE","DisplaySequence":0,"DescriptionTextPlain":"A1Testig"},

{"ProdDescription_ID":2865,"isAssigned":"TRUE","DisplaySequence":0,"DescriptionTextPlain":"test"},

{"ProdDescription_ID":1778,"isAssigned":"FALSE","DisplaySequence":0,"DescriptionTextPlain":"Testing4"},

{"ProdDescription_ID":2864,"isAssigned":"FALSE","DisplaySequence":0,"DescriptionTextPlain":"A2 "},

{"ProdDescription_ID":1544,"isAssigned":"FALSE","DisplaySequence":5,"DescriptionTextPlain":"ProductGuide"},

{"ProdDescription_ID":1535,"isAssigned":"TRUE","DisplaySequence":10,"DescriptionTextPlain":"testexample"},

{"ProdDescription_ID":1536,"isAssigned":"FALSE","DisplaySequence":15,"DescriptionTextPlain":"Note"}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use checked prop in `input` tag

```js
import "./styles.css";

import React from "react";

export class SetDescItems extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ProdDescrlist: [],
      checkedItems: []
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const id = parseInt(event.target.id, 10);
    const index = this.state.checkedItems.indexOf(id);
    const updatedArray = [...this.state.checkedItems];
    if (index !== -1) {
      updatedArray.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      updatedArray.push(id);
    }
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      checkedItems: updatedArray
    }));
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let value = "";

    this.state.checkedItems.forEach((item) => {
      if (item) {
        value = value === "" ? item : value + "," + item;
      }
    });

    if (value !== "") {
      alert(value);
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getProdDescriptions();
  }

  async getProdDescriptions() {
    const url = "/api/getDescriptions";
    await fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        let items = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
          if(item.isAssigned === "TRUE") acc.push(item.ProdDescription_ID);
          return acc;
        }, []);
        this.setState({
          ProdDescrlist: data,
          loading: false,
          checkedItems: items
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <ul style={{ listStyle: "none" }}>
            {this.state.ProdDescrlist.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <li key={index}>
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    id={item.ProdDescription_ID}
                    defaultChecked={item.isAssigned === "TRUE" ? true : false}
                    value={item.DescriptionTextPlain}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />
                  &nbsp;{item.DescriptionTextPlain}
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>

          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: By adding the checked={item.isAssigned === "TRUE"} works. It prefills the checkbox on page load.   Now, another problem i need to make a change in the Checkbox selection. I can uncheck the already selected checkboxes or check the unchecked checkboxes. checked={item.isAssigned === "TRUE"} is not allowing me to make any change in the Checkbox selection.      I need call update api to save the changed checkbox items.

Comment: Okay. So in that case you can use defaultChecked prop. Replace `checked={item.isAssigned === "TRUE"}` with `defaultChecked={item.isAssigned === "TRUE"}`

Comment: Thanks. I updated my code. Now, I need to make a change in the Checkbox selection. Please help me how to get the changed Checkboxes id's (some checkboxes are checked now and some are unchecked). I need the id's so I can call put api and save information in the database.

Comment: I have updated the code. Is this what you wanted to implement?

Comment: I have updated the code that pre-fills the checkboxes on the page load.

Comment: My Issue is Not sure how to get the selected id's of changed selection (User may uncheck the checked selection or user may check more options), how to achieve this. I need these id's on page submit to save information in the database.. What needs to be modified in the code? Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: So you just need the ids for selected checkboxes right? In that case in handleChange while updating the state, you can find whether the current id is present in checkedItems array and update the array accordingly.

Comment: Hi Sriram, Its giving the error whenever i try to make a change(check/uncheck) in the checkbox selection. Its not changing the selection. Its giving the error: TypeError: this.state.checkedItems.indexOf is not a function
 
const isChecked = event.target.checked;
const item = event.target.value;
const id = event.target.id;
const index = this.state.checkedItems.indexOf(id);
this.setState(prevState => ({
checkedItems: index !== -1 ? prevState.checkedItems.splice(index, 1) : prevState.checkedItems.push(id)
}));

Comment: I've updated my answer. And in your code change the changedItems to array in the state rather than Map

Comment: Hi Sriram, Thanks for the help in finding the solution. Status of Checkboxes are still not changing(Not able to uncheck/check the checkboxes). Click on any of the checkboxes are not doing anything.

Comment: Hey, I have updated the entire code and it is working perfectly

Comment: Thanks.  Changing the checkbox did start working.

Comment: On form submit, I am getting all selected checkbox id's( old and new). here is my javascript code. It's working. Just wondering is there a better way to do this in React.

Comment: I have updated the code and it works as you said

Comment: Please check my handleSubmit code.  i wrote the code in javascript. It's working. How the same code can be rewritten in react?

Comment: Actually if you use my code then in your handleSubmit function you would have all the checked items in checkedItems array.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sriram. It works great. I am new to React and I am still learning it. Thanks for all the help. What about if we need to check all checkboxes or uncheck all checkboxes?

Comment: To achieve that you can refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64451632/select-all-checkboxes-rows-react-hooks-app)